# Write integers and read them back from binary file in C++: number of bytes mismaych

Tags: c++, binary, integer, fstream

I'm writing four ints (a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4) to a binary file in C++ with `fstream`, but when I try to read them back, they do not match.

First of all, the written binary is 4 bytes long. Shouldn't it be 16 bytes (4 ints x 4 bytes/int)? When I read, I get the weird result `1234 2 3 4` if I do not zero-initialize the variables in the read function, or `1234 0 0 0` if I do.

Also, how is the result being modified by the zero-initialization? I know not initializating can lead to nasty results, but how exactly are the variables in read() getting those values that match the ones in write()?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void write()
{
    std::ofstream output( "test.bin", std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::out);
    int a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4;
    output << a << b << c << d;
    output.close();
}

void read()
{
    std::ifstream input( "test.bin", std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in);
    int a, b, c, d;
    // int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0;
    input >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    input.close();

    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << " " << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    write();
    read(); // Shows 1234 2 3 4 or 1234 0 0 0
}
```

Comment: [`operator<<(..., int)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is a _FormattedOutputFunction_. It's formatting the integers as strings with no separation between them. Concatenated strings of digits look indistinguishable from a single integer (1234) when you read it back. You can trivially confirm this by _looking_ at your own file. Use `hexdump` or similar to be safe if you expect it to be an un-printable binary file.

Comment: You are writing "1234", and then reading 1234 into `a`. The values of `b`, `c`, `d` are basically random, that's why the zero init changes them.

Comment: I was under the impression that for binary read/write, you want to use the stream's `.read`/`.write` functions.

Comment: @Cedric since c++11 `0` is assigned in case extraction failed. In any case there is nothing "random"

Comment: Thank you both. Yes, I understand why zero-initializations change variables, but not how. I expected what you are saying: that they would be random. But they are not random, they always are set to those numbers 2 3 4. Maybe the variables are being assigned the same memory that was set on write()?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 What makes you say that? In case of assignment (even in C++11 and later), I'd say nothing is passed to the variable since the stream failed before the extraction, meaning it retains it's previous value. In this example, they are clearly not `0` since the values are `1`, `2`, `3`. I assume they just happen to fall into the same memory as before, i.e. random.

Comment: @Cedric `int x; some_istream >> x;` assigns `0` to `x` in case extraction fails. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: @Cedric you are right, when the stream is already in a failstate then nothing is assigned: https://godbolt.org/z/WKhGM4.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Thanks for the link. The value is set to `0` if the **extraction fails**, e.g. if there was a `string` but we requested an `int`. However, in this case, the actual stream was invalid, meaning nothing gets extracted (and thus the value is not set to 0). See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Pqsfjf)

Comment: @Cedric actually thats scary, because that `0` assignment is pretty nice to avoid ub, but fails to do so with `std::cin >> x >> y;`. But enough of the spam ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
output << a << b << c << d;
```

is using the [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) stream insertion operator, which is for *formatted* output. All four integers are being formatted as strings, and output with no delimiter between them.

You can trivially see this by actually looking at your own file (use `hexdump` or similar if you expect the file to contain non-printable binary values). It contains the string `1234`, doesn't it?

You want *unformatted* output, meaning you don't want the stream to format your integers as strings. This is done by calling [`write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) instead (and [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) instead of `operator>>`).

Output:

```
output.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&a), sizeof(a));
output.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&b), sizeof(b));
// etc.
```

Input:

```
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&a), sizeof(a));
```

Your perhaps expected the `std::fstream::binary` openmode to prevent stream insertion formatting your integers as strings, but this is not correct: [binary mode](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/FILE#Binary_and_text_modes) only controls newline behaviour. The `<<` and `>>` operators are always for formatted I/O.